# calculations using both a value from a list and the index of that value?

Tags: python, list, indexing

I need to perform a calculation on a list using both the values of that list, and the index of those values, eg:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]

b= a[1]*1
```

but for all values of a, to get:

```
b = [1,4,9,16,25]
```

Is this possible to do without a for loop? I could put it in one, but it would change the structure of my code for the worse. This is meant to be used by a wide variety of users with varying skill levels, so I'm willing to sacrifice speed for ease of readability.

Comment: @AvinashRaj This should be an answer right? :)

Comment: @KevinGuan he asked a solution without a for loop. But the above has one.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Sorry, didn't see that :P

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear! I didn't realize that it was possible to write a for loop within the definition of an array as Anand did

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use list comprehension and `enumerate()` function, that provides the index as well as value of the element, simultaneously. Example -

```
b = [elem * (i+1) for i, elem in enumerate(a)]
```

Demo -

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> b = [elem * (i+1) for i, elem in enumerate(a)]
>>> b
[1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
```

---

If its fine to use `numpy` library , most probably a faster solution would be to use numpy's vectorised multiplication . Example -

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: a = [1,2,3,4,5]

In [3]: a_arr = np.array(a)

In [4]: b = a_arr * np.arange(1,a_arr.shape[0]+1)

In [5]: b
Out[5]: array([ 1,  4,  9, 16, 25])
```

Though numpy method may be a bit more complex to understand that the list comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use `map` built-in function and let your code be simpler.

```
a =  [1,2,3,4,5]

b = map(lambda x: x*x, a)

print b
# [1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
```

If you want to dynamically enter your list, you would use `range` built-in function (It's available for python2):

```
b = map(lambda x: x*x, range(1,6))

print b
# [1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
```